# LINQ: Get data from linked tables (many-to-many relation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project and existing DB (MS SQLServer). I already have scaffolded models from db:

Component.cs

```
public partial class 
{
    public Component()
    {
        ComponentDocumentationLink = new HashSet<ComponentDocumentationLink>();

    }

    public int IdConponent { get; set; }
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public string ComponentTitle { get; set; }
    public string ComponentDescription { get; set; }
    public int IdComponentType { get; set; }
    public int IdrecStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public string ChangeUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ComponentDocumentationLink> ComponentDocumentationLink { get; set; }
    public virtual ComponentType IdComponentTypeNavigation { get; set; }

}
```

ComponentType.cs

```
public partial class ComponentType
{
    public ComponentType()
    {
        Component = new HashSet<Component>();
    }

    public int IdComponentType { get; set; }
    public string ComponentTypeName { get; set; }
    public int IdrecStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public string ChangeUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Component> Component { get; set; }
}
```

ComponentDocumentationLink.cs

```
public partial class ComponentDocumentationLink
{
    public int IdComponentDocumentationLink { get; set; }
    public int IdComponent { get; set; }
    public int IdDocumentation { get; set; }
    public int IdrecStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public string ChangeUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Component IdComponentNavigation { get; set; }

    public virtual Documentation IdDocumentationNavigation { get; set; }


}
```

and Documentation.cs

```
public partial class Documentation
{
    public Documentation()
    {
        ComponentDocumentationLink = new HashSet<ComponentDocumentationLink>();
    }

    public int IdDocumentation { get; set; }
    public int IdDocumentationType { get; set; }
    public string DocumentationSrc { get; set; }
    public int IdrecStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public string ChangeUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ComponentDocumentationLink> ComponentDocumentationLink { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentationType IdDocumentationTypeNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

[image: a db model]

The problem is that I have link-table ComponentDocumentationLink between Component and Documentation (many-to-many relation) and no table between Component and ComponentType (one-to-one relation).

When I'm trying to get ComponentType for each Component in controller then I have no problem with `var components = db.Component.Include(ct => ct.IdComponentTypeNavigation);`, but there is no use of this query for retrieving data from Documentation for each Component.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution.

```
db.Something.Include(x => x.SomethingJunction).ThenInclude(x => x.JunctionedTable);
```

And then in a view:

```
@var a = item.SomethinJunction.Select(x => x.JunctionedTable);
@a.Property;
```